# Implementing a blog entry link

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an application like a blog engine. On a view for a home page, I have a link as

```
<a href="/Blog/BlogEntry/2013/05/22/title for this blog entry" />
```

when user click on that link it will come to a Blog controller and run a BlogEntry action there

```
public class BlogController : Controller {
   public ActionResult BlogEntry(string title, DateTime createdDate) {
       // doing something
       var viewModel = something here for build the view model

       return View(viewModel);
   }
}
```

The question is how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this , as all the parameter will map from URL. Use the action filter to map the data the way you want. I am not completely tested the code , but it will give  the fare idea. Add this attribute above your action.

```
   public ActionResult BlogEntry(int year, int month , int day , string title)

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
     using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace OurAttributes
    {
     public class PopulateTitleDandDateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
     {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

                string[] url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Uri.split('/');
                DateTime d = new Date(url[2],url[3],url[4]);
                if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("createdDate"))
                {
                    filterContext.ActionParameters["createdDate"] = d;
                }

                if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("title"))
                {
                    filterContext.ActionParameters["title"] = url[5] ;
                }
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);


    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment. But I want to submit to the function like BlogEntry(string title, DateTime createdDate). That is my requirement.

Comment: @ThangChung I have updated my solution to use the actionfilter to populate the CreatedDate and title as you want. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

As Devesh suggestion, I have modified something in his code, and it worked

- Controller:

  ```
  [HttpGet]
  [PopulateTitleDandDate]
  public ActionResult BlogEntry(string title, DateTime createdDate)
  {
      var viewModel = new BlogEntryModel
          {
              Tittle = title,
              CreatedDate = createdDate
          };

      return View(viewModel);
  }
  ```
- PopulateTitleDandDateAttribute

  ```
  public class PopulateTitleDandDateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
          var url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl.Split('/');
          if (url.Length >= 7) // TODO: it is actually not good here
          {
              var d = new DateTime(url[3].ConvertToInteger(), url[4].ConvertToInteger(), url[5].ConvertToInteger());
              if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("createdDate"))
              {
                  filterContext.ActionParameters["createdDate"] = d;
              }

              if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("title"))
              {
                  filterContext.ActionParameters["title"] = url[6];
              }
          }

          base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
      }
  }
  ```
- BlogEntry.cshtml

  ```
  @model SampleApplication.Controllers.BlogEntryModel

  <h2>@Html.Raw(Model.Tittle) (@Html.Raw(Model.CreatedDate))</h2>
  ```

Thanks Devesh once again.